# Which method is more elegant method to write Event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When writing code I always want to find a more elegant way. Better readability and better efficiency. Which method do you prefer? Or you have other better method.

### Method 1

In my opinion, It's an ugly method, Mixed code.

```
class Layer extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <li
        onClick={(event)=>{
          console.log(event.target, this.props.layerId);
          // Some Code
        }}
      >
        {layerName}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

---

### Method 2

Common method. But every click will create an anonymous function. Efficiency?

```
class Layer extends Component {
  onLayerClick(event){
    console.log(event.target, this.props.layerId);
    // Some Code
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <li
        onClick={(event)=>{
          this.onLayerClick(event);
        }}
      >
        {layerName}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

---

### Method 3

My favorite method. But need to bind.

```
class Layer extends Component {
  onLayerClick(event){
    console.log(event.target, this.props.layerId);
    // Some Code
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <li
        onClick={this.onLayerClick.bind(this)}
      >
        {layerName}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `.bind` also creates a new function. So 2 and 3 are the same (really, all of these work exactly the same way, so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`)

Comment: @FelixKling In my mind. Elegant is not just efficient. Readability is also very important. Which one you feel more comfortable when you read the code?

Comment: Well, in that case you are asking for a subjective opinion, which is off-topic ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Most of the things in this world are not binary opposition. It's not just right or wrong.When I'm learning such things, I want to listen to some people’s subjective opinions. Subjective opinions are precious for me. Analyze them and you will get a better answer than the right answer. If the code is functional and no bugs, then it's right, but it's not necessarily elegant.

Comment: I’m not saying that it is. And I’m not saying that this question itself isn’t worth asking. I’m only saying that these kind of questions are not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Felix Kling Maybe! :( Because my other similar question was closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199234/which-method-is-more-elegant-method-to-return-a-calculated-object-properties  But I always wanted to find a platform. many people can submit the code with same function. And other people can judge the most elegant code. I just use StackOverflow few days, not understand the rules. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) your question might actually be OK. I encourage you to read it so that you phrase your question such that they are useful for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very opinion and context-based, but property initialized arrow functions makes it so you don't have to `bind` in the render method or in the constructor.

```
class Layer extends Component {
  onLayerClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target, this.props.layerId);
  };

  render(){
    return <li onClick={this.onLayerClick}>{layerName}</li>;
  }
}
```

However, [class properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are not in the language yet, so not all development environments will have access to them. The second best option in my opinion is to `bind` the method in the constructor. It's a bit more to write than the class properties option, but you don't need to create a new function in the render method each time.

```
class Layer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLayerClick = this.onLayerClick.bind(this);
  }

  onLayerClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target, this.props.layerId);
  };

  render(){
    return <li onClick={this.onLayerClick}>{layerName}</li>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used this method. But jshint has been reporting an error. Let me thought it's not the standard way of class.

Comment: @LaneZhao You're right. It's currently a proposal, so you might not be able to use it in some development environments, and some linters might not agree with it.

Comment: So except this, which one you prefer?

Comment: @LaneZhao I updated the answer with my second favorite option.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way:

```js
class Example extends Component {

  handleClick = (e) => {
      console.log("EVENT:, e") 

  }
  
  render()  {
     return (
       <div>
         <button 
           onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Click Me!
          </button>
      )
    }
}
```

Its automatically bound to the `this` of your component, and imho looks cleander

Answer (score 0):

I use two versions in my code, depending on the need for state (that is when I use a non-functional component).

Functional:

```
export default functional MyComponent({ layerName, layerId }) {
  return (
    <li onClick={onLayerClick}>{layerName}</li>
  )

  function onLayerClick(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget, layerId)
  }
}
```

Non-functional:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.onLayerClick}>{this.props.layerName}</li>
    )
  }

  onLayerClick = e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget, this.props.layerId)
  }
}
```

Note that the second (non-functional) version uses [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) which is currently at Stage 3.